# Sort Dewey Decimal list?

Tags: regular-expressions, sorting

If I have a list of books' call numbers in Dewey Decimal in a buffer, is this something I could sort with Emacs regex -- or is this an elisp task? For example, `261.1 C87` comes before `261.104 Z99` because the first one can be understood as `261.100 C87`. So each column/place must be compared. And then of course the alphabet parts, which means `261.1 C87` comes before `261.1 Ch2`. I'm just wondering if there are any Emacs regex experts who would see a good way. Otherwise, I'll just do elisp on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use command **`sort-numeric-fields`**.

`C-h f sort-numeric-fields` tells you:

> sort-numeric-fields is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in
>       `sort.el`.
>
> It is bound to menu-bar edit sort sort-numeric-fields.
>
> `(sort-numeric-fields FIELD BEG END)`
>
> Sort lines in region numerically by the ARGth field of each line.
>       Fields are separated by whitespace and numbered from 1 up.
>       Specified field must contain a number in each line of the region,
>       which may begin with "0x" or "0" for hexadecimal and octal values.
>       Otherwise, the number is interpreted according to sort-numeric-base.
>       With a negative arg, sorts by the ARGth field counted from the right.
>       Called from a program, there are three arguments:
>       FIELD, BEG and END.  BEG and END specify region to sort.

See also the Emacs manual, node [Sorting](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Sorting.html).  There you see, in addition to a general explanation of sorting and descriptions of other sorting commands:

> **`M-x sort-fields`**
>
> Divide the region into lines, and sort by comparing the contents of
>            one field in each line.  Fields are defined as separated by
>            whitespace, so the first run of consecutive non-whitespace
>            characters in a line constitutes field 1, the second such run
>            constitutes field 2, etc.
>
> Specify which field to sort by with a numeric argument: 1 to sort
>            by field 1, etc.  A negative argument means count fields from the
>            right instead of from the left; thus, minus 1 means sort by the
>            last field.  If several lines have identical contents in the field
>            being sorted, they keep the same relative order that they had in
>            the original buffer.
>
> **`M-x sort-numeric-fields`**
>
> Like `M-x sort-fields` except the specified field is converted to
>            an integer for each line, and the numbers are compared.  `10` comes
>            before `2` when considered as text, but after it when considered as
>            a number.  By default, numbers are interpreted according to
>            `sort-numeric-base`, but numbers beginning with `0x` or `0` are
>            interpreted as hexadecimal and octal, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the good info, Drew. Actually, a `M-x sort-lines` did the trick. Apparently, I was in over-kill mode.